# Ecs deploy fail due to insufficient cpu units and some times time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I just installed ecs-deploy using pip install ecs-deploy.When I try to deploy getting error like

First time I got :

```
Deploying based on task definition: task-demo:2

Creating new task definition revision
Successfully created revision: 3

Updating service
Successfully changed task definition to: task-demo:3

Deploying new task definition..........
2020-01-26 14:12:57.563000+00:00
ERROR: (service demo-service) was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching (container-instance ba93b620-89fa-4970-bf54-535a373d1aba) has insufficient CPU units available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.

Deployment failed
```

from second time onwards:

```
Deploying based on task definition: task-demo:5

Creating new task definition revision
Successfully created revision: 6

Updating service
Successfully changed task definition to: task-demo:6

Deploying new task definition...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Deployment failed due to timeout. Please see: https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy#timeout
```

Comment: @Rodrigo M Can you help with this

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error message if the closest matching container instance for task placement doesn't have enough CPU units to meet the requirements of the task definition.

You will want to check the remaining CPU units on your container instances, and make adjustments to meet the CPU requirements.

Here is a resource for troubleshooting this issue:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-instance-cpu-error/

Regarding the time out issue, note that the deploy and scale actions of the `ecs` command allow defining a timeout (in seconds) via the --timeout parameter. This instructs ecs-deploy to wait for ECS to finish the deployment for the given number of seconds.

See https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy#deployment-timeout

Try and fix the CPU problem first. It's likely that the timeout issue is related.

Comment: Hi, I had this issue but in a strange case scencario, If I try to configure the pipeline to make the automatic deploy, that error arise, but If I restart the cluster task manually (stopping it from the cluser UI) it works perfect and also the CPU units are correct... I'm using less than the total of CPU units available for my instance. Could be this related to another issue? thanks